# More than one 'And' operator in ASP if statment?

Tags: if-statement, asp-classic, conditional-statements

Sorry I am new to ASP. I found a strange problem in the If statement

For example , I use this condition

```
if sear_type="4" and rs_search_news("search_field")="2"  and show_str2<>1 then
....
Endif
```

And it is not work as expected . Is ASP not allow writing condition like this? Thanks

Comment: check that the variables have the values you expect them to have, using `response.write` and also consider the types: `show_str2<>1` is not the same as `show_str2<>"1"`. You could also give each condition within parentheses : `if (sear_type="4") and (rs_search_news("search_field")="2")  and (show_str2<>1) then`

Comment: you can also cast the variables for checking: `if (CStr(sear_type)="4") and (CStr(rs_search_news("search_field"))="2") and (CInt(show_str2)<>1) then`

Comment: Just to add to the point made by @SearchAndResQ, is the last variable a string - `show_str2`.  If so then you're actually comparing it to a number value.  You could try putting the `1` in double qoutes, like so: `show_str2<>"1"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work just fine, probably something else is wrong.

Try this for start, and if still not working please explain exactly what's wrong.

```vbs
If (sear_type="4") And (rs_search_news("search_field")="2") And (show_str2<>1) Then
    '....
End If
```